# Python: How to choose specific number that is divisible by two numbers, but prints only the chosen number?

Tags: python

Sorry if my post is messy or hard to understand. I am just learning to code and to understand python. I have a homework where I am given n1 (random number from 0-10) and n2(from 30-45). My job is to print every number between n1 and n2 that is divisible by 2 but not by 3.

```
for x in range(n1,n2):
if x%2==0:
    print(x)
    
if x%3==0:
    continue
```

So this is my code now. I have tried it and it works, but it prints numbers like 6 and 12 that are divisible by 3. Hod do I fix it?

Comment: Your code has syntax errors. Indentation is critical in Python. Please fix it by editing your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add an extra condition here:

```
for x in range(n1,n2):

   if x % 2 == 0 and x % 3 != 0:

       print(x)
```

Or to have the `continue` happen *before* the print such as:

```
for x in range(n1,n2):

   if x%3 == 0:
       continue

   if x%2 == 0:
       print(x)
```

What was happening was that you were printing first, and then checking the condition for divisibility by 3, which meant that even though you "skipped" the loop, you had already printed anyway.

Comment: The conditions could also be used as `if not x%2`, as this will evaluate to True if the remainder is zero.
Furthermore, beware that `range` includes the lower bound, but excludes the upper one. So `range(a, b)` will go from `a` to `b-1`. If your goal is to go all the way to `b`, you must use `range(a, b+1)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose random number between 0-10 for n1 and 30-45 for n2. Import random module and use `randint()` to get random nos. Also, you can put both the conditions in same `if` statement. Your code:

```
import random
n1=random.randint(0,10)
n2=random.randint(30,45)
for i in range(n1,n2):
    if i%2==0 and i%3!=0:
        print(i)
```